# Ajax - Why use JSON.parse(data) with dataType in $.post()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I use ajax to fill a datatables table dynamically.

Here is the code:

**Javascript :**

```
  $.post("/import_data.php", {add: new_row}, "json").done(function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);

    if (data[0] === 'example_1') {
      .....
      $("#error_1").modal("show");
    }
    else if (data[0] === 'example_2') {
      .....
      $("#error_2").modal("show");
    }
    else {
      table.row.add(data).order([0, 'desc']).draw();
    } 
  });
```

**PHP (import_data.php) :**

```
 ...    
 $arr = array('info1', 'info2', 'info3', 'info4');
 echo json_encode($arr);
```

But there is something that I do not understand, why I have to use the line `JSON.parse (data)`, it's not the work of the dataType or there is a problem in my code?

How can I improve my script?

**EDIT :**

Console.log(data) -- before JSON.parse(data) :

```
["super","1","220","example"]
```

After JSON.parse(data) :

```
(4) ["super", "1", "220", "example"]
0: "super"
1: "1"
2: "220"
3: "example"
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

If I do not put `JSON.parse(data)`
Rather than taking me the `super` element, he takes me `[`

Comment: JSON.parse(data); You get a json and make an array out of it. Then you can work better with it. nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: @DieterKräutl - The OP is passing `"json"` as the third argument, which means jQuery will have already done that for him/her. See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes you are right., sorry!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My example works but I do not understand why. When I do not put ``data = JSON.parse (data)``, I have an error in my DataTables. The DataType can not avoid this line? Since he should understand that the answer is json?

Comment: @Rocstar  what is the error?

Comment: Thank for your help, I edited my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm shocked to find that the data is not parsed when passed to the `done` callback when you rely on the `dataType` parameter (I've replicated your problem locally) in your example. It's because jQuery's `$.post` requires you to pass an argument for the `success` parameter if you're going to include a `dataType` parameter; see [Aditya Sharma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52310430/157247) for a quote from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) on that.

You shouldn't rely on the `dataType` parameter anyway, though; instead, your PHP should return the correct `Content-Type` header:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$arr = array('info1', 'info2', 'info3', 'info4');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

If you do that, your `$.post` call works just fine (**without** the `JSON.parse` call).

If for some reason you can't do that, use the success callback instead of `done` (or pass `null` as the `success` parameter and keep using `.done`); jQuery will parse the JSON for you because of the `"json"` parameter:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
$.post("temp.php", {add: new_row}, function(data) {
    // ...
}, "json");

// or
$.post("temp.php", {add: new_row}, null, "json").done(function(data) {
    // ...
}, "json");
```

...and then, again, no need for the `JSON.parse` call.

But again, it's better if the PHP correctly identifies the type of the response.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly, I have trouble with the concept of "done", "success" or "error" but I will document. However with your method how can I handle errors for example?

Comment: @Rocstar - I'm not sure which way you're going (success callback or specifying the correct Content-Type), but if you use the correct Content-Type, you can use `.done` and `.fail` if you want. If you have to use the `dataType` parameter because the Content-Type is wrong (which is a bad idea), use the `success` and `error` callbacks on `$.ajax` rather than `$.post`.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence of dataType is wrong.

> jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )

As per the official [doc](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

> A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds. Required
>   if dataType is provided, but can be null in that case.

Try this

```
$.post("/import_data.php", {add: new_row}, function(data){

    if (data[0] === 'example_1') {
      .....
      $("#error_1").modal("show");
    }
    else if (data[0] === 'example_2') {
      .....
      $("#error_2").modal("show");
    }
    else {
      table.row.add(data).order([0, 'desc']).draw();
    } 
}, "json");
```

Or try setting callback to undefined

```
$.post("/import_data.php", {add: new_row}, null, "json").done(function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);

    if (data[0] === 'example_1') {
      .....
      $("#error_1").modal("show");
    }
    else if (data[0] === 'example_2') {
      .....
      $("#error_2").modal("show");
    }
    else {
      table.row.add(data).order([0, 'desc']).draw();
    } 
  });
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamaditya/qwgxfvtz/6/)

Comment: Thank you but I only execute my script when I'm in "done", in my case it becomes  : `` $.post("/import_data.php", {add: new_row}).done(function(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        ... 
      }, "json"); ``
 ?

Comment: @Rocstar You can pass null as the third parameter in that case

Comment: Good stuff, but why are you using `undefined` when the documentation says to use `null`? I mean, even if it works, I'd stick with the documentation (and it's shorter ;-) ).

Comment: Indeed. I tried with null first I guess I misread the console log with some old errors. Updated the answer and fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

### if you are request with `$.post` then first you require the parse json array and then get a array value. otherwise u can use ajax call it is better and u don't need to require `Json.parse` directly you can get the array value.

example :

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "your url",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {data: value},
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data[0])
            console.log(data[0]);
            //data = JSON.parse(data);
        },
```

=> Check and try with this.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's great that you've tried to help Rocstar here, but a few things: 1. It's not appropriate to make your entire post **boldface** and extra large. 2. It's important to be sure the information you're providing is correct; the information in this answer is wrong, using `$.post` does not mean you have to use `JSON.parse` yourself. 3. "Better" is a subjective term best avoided in answers (and questions).